# How to add layers on camera view for showing labels with geolocation data depending on the location of the device, like in ZipRealty Real Estate app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, geolocation, camera

How do I add information about an object that has a geolocation data to the camera view like in the picture below (screen takes from ZipRealty Real Estate app). And to change labels when the user rotates on its axis.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a transparent UIView on top of the camera view and add your labels there.

According to the location of the device and its orientation (using the compass), you should find which objects are facing the camera now and use that information to update the labels. You update this information every time the location or orientation changes.

In other words, you don't recognize objects by the camera, but with the location and the orientation of the device.

Comment: What should I use to get device orientation? I think that I need something like in compass app.

Comment: Yes, I mean you should use the compass to determine the device orientation.

Comment: So as I see this feather will work only on iPhone and iPad not on iPod?

Comment: So it's impossible to get device compass orientation just using accelerometer?

Comment: Yes. you can't get that from the accelerometer. The compass app isn't available for devices that don't have a compass, because it would not function.